# How can SSG+i18n+dynamic routes be managed in NextJS ^14, strictly using the pages router?

Tags: next.js, internationalization, next.js13, next-translate

In an effort to facilitate the nextjs upgrade (12 -> 14), it's become unclear how to configure i18n in an SSG app only using dynamic catch all routes leveraging the `pages` router.

The crux of the problem is NextJS is now erroring for SSG when setting `i18n` in config. When it's removed and `locales` are side loaded in `getStaticPaths`, the build errors out indicating locale is not specified in config.

Can someone please point to the changes necessary to facilitate this upgrade? `next-translate` is currently used to handle i18n but is not a requirement to maintain; SSG, i18n, the `pages` router and dynamic catch all routes are.

`next.config.js`:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  i18n: {
    locales, defaultLocale,
    localeDetection: false,
  },
```

`./src/pages/[[...slug]].js` (dynamic catch all route):

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async ({ locales }) => {
  const paths = [];
  await Promise.all(locales?.map(async (locale) => {
    // fetch and parse entries, then:
    paths.push({ params: { slug }, locale });
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  };
};
```

`i18n.js`:

```js
module.exports={
  "localeDetection": false,
  "locales": [
    "en-US",
    "es"
  ],
  "defaultLocale": "en-US",
  "loadLocaleFrom": (lang, ns) => import(`./locales/${lang}/${ns}.json`).then((m) => m.default),
  "pages": {
    "*": [
      "common"
    ]
  },
  "logBuild": false
};
```

Versions:

- **node**: 20.11.0
- **next**: 14.1.0
- **react**: 18.2.0
- **next-translate**: 2.6.2

Given the previous/original `next.config.js`, the build fails, logging `i18n` *cannot* be specified in `next.config.js` if `output: 'export'` is also set. Yet, removing `i18n` surfaces issues w/in `getStaticProps`:

1. `locales` does not exist in NextJS cache, given if no `i18n` is set in config. Previously, `locales` (from NextJS context) was mapped over as a part of `paths` generation, e.g. `getStaticPaths` snippet above.
2. Attempting to side-load `locales` w/in `getStaticPaths`, e.g.:

```js
import i18n from '../../i18n';
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { locales } = i18n;
```

Yields the following error:

```
Error: Invalid locale returned from getStaticPaths for /[[...slug]], the locale en-US is not specified in next.config.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build is completing when using [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to comment out two errors relating to `i18n` use w/ SSG. In effect, this patch circumvents seemingly needless restrictions imposed by NextJS (at least on `v13.x.x`) to prevent i18n with static export.

`next+13.4.9.patch`

```js
diff --git a/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js b/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js
index f0579c2..57dc01a 100644
--- a/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js
+++ b/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js
@@ -326,9 +326,9 @@ async function exportApp(dir, options, span) {
             };
         }
         const { i18n , images: { loader ="default" , unoptimized  }  } = nextConfig;
-        if (i18n && !options.buildExport) {
-            throw new ExportError(`i18n support is not compatible with next export. See here for more info on deploying: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-no-custom-routes`);
-        }
+        // if (i18n && !options.buildExport) {
+        //     throw new ExportError(`i18n support is not compatible with next export. See here for more info on deploying: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-no-custom-routes`);
+        // }
         if (!options.buildExport) {
             const { isNextImageImported  } = await nextExportSpan.traceChild("is-next-image-imported").traceAsyncFn(()=>_fs.promises.readFile((0, _path.join)(distDir, _constants1.EXPORT_MARKER), "utf8").then((text)=>JSON.parse(text)).catch(()=>({})));
             if (isNextImageImported && loader === "default" && !unoptimized && !_ciinfo.hasNextSupport) {
diff --git a/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js b/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js
index 90a4db3..dc40674 100644
--- a/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js
+++ b/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js
@@ -211,9 +211,9 @@ function assignDefaults(dir, userConfig, silent = false) {
         ...config
     };
     if (result.output === "export") {
-        if (result.i18n) {
-            throw new Error('Specified "i18n" cannot be used with "output: export". See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-no-i18n');
-        }
+        // if (result.i18n) {
+        //     throw new Error('Specified "i18n" cannot be used with "output: export". See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-no-i18n');
+        // }
         if (result.rewrites) {
             throw new Error('Specified "rewrites" cannot be used with "output: export". See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-no-custom-routes');
         }
```

`next.config.js`:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate');

const i18n = require('./i18n');

const { locales, defaultLocale } = i18n;

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  i18n: { locales, defaultLocale },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [
      {
        generateBuildId: async () => 'build',
      }
    ],
    nextTranslate
  ],
  nextConfig
);
```

Versions used in current working build (changed from those specified in the question):

- **next**: 13.4.9
- **next-translate**: 1.0.7